# Is there some popular naming convention for closure factory functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, closures, naming-conventions

I'm writing a javascript style guide for my developer teams, and I try to put in some naming conventions.

To avoid nested closures, I added a rule into the guide saying to write closure factories instead of nesting it (and write named callbacks in the root level instead of nesting it). It permit to flatten function definitions and set the maximum nesting level to 2.

For example, instead of this :

```
function main (userName) {
  var foo = ['bar', 'baz']

  foo.forEach(function (item) {
    console.info(userName + ' add the ' + item + 'event listener')
    document.addEventListener(item, function (evt) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('event fired: ', evt.type)
      }, 1000)
    })
  })
}
```

The rule say to do this :

```
function main (userName) {
  var foo = ['bar', 'baz']

  _.forEach(foo, createClosure_addEachListener(userName))
}

function createClosure_addEachListener (userName) {
  return addEachListener

  function addEachListener (item) {
    console.info(userName + ' add the ' + item + 'event listener')
    document.addEventListener(item, logEventIn1Second)
  }
}

function logEventIn1Second (evt) {
  var functionToCall = logEvent.bind(evt.type)
  doItIn1Second(functionToCall)
}

function doItIn1Second (func) {
  setTimeout(func, 1000)
}

function logEvent (type) {
  console.log('event fired: ', type)
}
```

> This example is intentionally overdone. In such simple cases, of course, no need to apply this rule, which make the code harder to read, here. But if the closures are more complex or take many lines of code, this rule can significantly reduce the size of function definitions and simplify the reading of the code. Moreover, this technique has a very significant performance effect. Indeed, in the first example (nested closures), the anonymous function containing the `setTimeout` call and the anonymous function containing the `console.log` call are defined as many as the length of the array, due to the fact they are defined into the `foo.forEach` loop callback. On the other side, the second case (following the 'flatten closure' rule), the closures that doesn't use any closure's scope vars are transformed to standard functions (or callbacks), not closures. And moreover, they are defined once.

So the rule say two thing :

- flatten all function definitions (unless they are very simple)
- if the function is a closure (if the function use at least one var of the closure scope), create a wrapper function (in the example: `createClosure_addEachListener`) that return the closure, and pass all needed vars as arguments of the wrapper function, to recreate the minimal needed scope for the closure.

## my question

So, in my example I called the wrapper function `createClosure_addEachListener`. And I use to name this king of function this way (`createClosure_<closureName>`).

But I searched if it exists somewhere a standard or just popular convention to name this kind of **closure factories**.

Anybody know such naming conventions ?

Comment: `foo.each`? that library is that?  `_.forEach` what stands that `_` for? I have the vague feeling you're mashing simple callbacks with closures (functions defined and instantiated/returned within the scope of a parent function)...

Comment: Yes, `foo.forEach`, it was a typo, sorry, I fixed it in the post. But it's not really the subject of the question though. No I don't confound closures and callbacks, I thought be clear about that in the orange citation block, especially saying « On the other side, the second case (following the 'flatten closure' rule), the closures that doesn't use any closure's scope vars are transformed to standard functions (or callbacks), not closures »

Comment: There is then a naming convention for that?